# dropdown menu display number instead of the list

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a responsive dropdown menu. Based on the coding in script.js, the job-title dropdown should display the title that I have been listed in the list according to their field. But, the output doesn't display the title. It shows number. I have attached the image below.

Here is the following code for HTML and JS file code snippet:

```js
var jobInfo = {
    "Information Technology and Software Development": ["Senior Frontend Developer", "Data Processing Specialist", "Java Developer"],
    "Digital Marketing": ["Digital Marketing Web Specialist", "Video Editor", "Graphic Designer"],
    "Finance": ["Financial Analyst-SSC", "Accountant", "Specialist, Business Finance (APAC)"]
}
window.onload = function() {
  var jobField = document.getElementById("job-field");
  var jobTitle = document.getElementById("job-title");
  for (var x in jobInfo) {
    jobField.options[jobField.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  jobField.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    jobTitle.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in jobInfo[this.value]) {
      jobTitle.options[jobTitle.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UPLOAD FILE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="job">
            <h2>Choose job's field: </h2>
            <select name="job-field" id="job-field">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select field</option>
            </select>
              <br><br>
            <h2>Choose job's title: </h2>
            <select name="job-title" id="job-title">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select title</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="upload">
            <h2>Upload a CSV file</h2>
            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="file">
              <br><br>
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for...in` iterates over the properties, or indices in the case of an array. Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more details. [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) might work better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) seams more suitable for this case instead of [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). As explained, `for...in` returns the index if used with an Array.

Updating

```js
for (var y in jobInfo[this.value]) {
    jobTitle.options[jobTitle.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
}
```

to below should do the trick

```js
for (var y of jobInfo[this.value]) {
    jobTitle.options[jobTitle.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, which is iterating over properties in an object. Therefore the variable you are using inside the for loop is holding the property name.

In your first loop it's working, because the objects property is also your jobtitle.

In your second loop, you are looping over an array which holds your job titles. This array is also an object, where the "property" is your arrays index. So your variable `y` inside your for loop only holds the index for your value, which is 0, 1, 2 ...
In order to access the actual value you have to use `jobInfo[this.value][y]`

So the new option you are adding need to change from `new Option(y, y);` to `new Option(jobInfo[this.value][y], y);`

Fixed code below

```js
var jobInfo = {
    "Information Technology and Software Development": ["Senior Frontend Developer", "Data Processing Specialist", "Java Developer"],
    "Digital Marketing": ["Digital Marketing Web Specialist", "Video Editor", "Graphic Designer"],
    "Finance": ["Financial Analyst-SSC", "Accountant", "Specialist, Business Finance (APAC)"]
};

window.onload = function() {
  var jobField = document.getElementById("job-field");
  var jobTitle = document.getElementById("job-title");
  
  for (var x in jobInfo) {
    jobField.options[jobField.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  
  jobField.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    jobTitle.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in jobInfo[this.value]) {
      jobTitle.options[jobTitle.options.length] = new Option(jobInfo[this.value][y], y);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UPLOAD FILE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="job">
            <h2>Choose job's field: </h2>
            <select name="job-field" id="job-field">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select field</option>
            </select>
              <br><br>
            <h2>Choose job's title: </h2>
            <select name="job-title" id="job-title">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select title</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="upload">
            <h2>Upload a CSV file</h2>
            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="file">
              <br><br>
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```